# How to create a Login and Registration page in Objective-C and how connect it to the server?

Tags: php, iphone, xcode

I want to create a Login and Registration page in Objective-C but I am very new in iPhone programming. How can i create that pages and how connect it to the server?
Thanks to everyone can help me!

Comment: Are you looking to create a native iPhone application or a web-app?

Comment: I want to create a native app because I need to check if the UDID is in my server database! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with a server using HTTP using [the URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to expose the login and registration functionality as a web service, then you'll consume that service from the iPhone. 
Typically, you'll use an NSURLConnection to asynchronously connect to the web service, return your results as an XML document, parse the XML with an NSXMLParser, and react accordingly.

There's definitely also the possibility of creating a socket connection to the server and communicating over your own protocol, but using a web service makes things much easier and allows you to easily support other devices in the future.